# Websphere server encryption and Decryption

Tags: web-services, encryption, apache-axis

I have developed a web service example using Axis1/Axis2 frame work.
Am using websphere as server.
Using SOAP UI a,able send request and get the response.
How to encrypt the request and response.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose between TLS, WS-Security or you could apply both. Furthermore, you can of course always implement security in your application protocol as well, but that may be harder than it looks at first sight. To note: I think about 90% of WS-Security was broken at a specific time (due to oracle attacks on XML encryption) so even "professionals" can get it wrong.

An introduction in any of these technologies is far beyond the scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: WS-Security : how to configure this in web sphere ?     Or Any third party APIs need to be used?